# How to Trigger a function inside a JQuery file jquery.js from a html <form>

Tags: jquery

Lets say This is my html form definition:

```
     <form id="feedback" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

The jQuery file is defined in the head tag:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxarchive.js"></script>
```

I've also created a html div within an input field as a button:

```
     <div id ="button" class="button">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" />
     </div>
```

I have JavaScript code inside my index.html and I prefer keep the code to validate my form outside the index.htm. I could add my functions
in a sentence like this (but I rather want to call my functions from an external file):

```
     if ($li_e.attr('class')==='cc_content_13'){
        /*here I try to recieve code from the ajaxarchive.js inside functions*/
     }
```

How I define the functions also inside the ajaxarchive.js in order to to something like

```
   var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData); <-- This is the name of the function
```

Comment: Whaaaat? Can you please take the time to make this question readable?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to hook up some validation logic to the clicking of the "Submit" button without modifying the actual HTML to include a reference.  If that's the case then just bind to the `click` event in an external js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    // Call your function here.  

  });
});
```

Comment: my own answer<form id="feedback" action="javascript:checa('#feedback');" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to your form's "submit" event. You can define your function anywhere you wish, as long as you include its source file before calling $.ready.

```
// somewhere in $(document).ready:
$("#feedback").submit(yourExternalFunctionNameHere);
```

Where parameter e in the function is the event object. Make sure to call e.preventDefault() or return false inside the function so the form won't submit by default - you can submit it manually by using:

```
$("#feedback").submit();
```

Comment: I fond a better solution I just addead in the action field the name of my JQuery function and the form (as a paremeter). This to get my form validate externally to my index.html

Comment: @user972593: you can post it as an answer, and later accept it